# Struts 1 Validation Field x OR y Required

Tags: validation, struts-1

For the Struts 1 validation XML file, is it possible to say that field x OR field y is required?

Here is the syntax that I have in the xml file:

```
<form name="/save">
    <field property="email" depends="required">
            <arg0 key="Email" resource="false"/>
        </field>
    <field property="phone" depends="required">
        <arg0 key="Phone" resource="false"/>
    </field>
</form>
```

The above snippet requires BOTH email and phone to be filled out. I want to require either email OR phone.

Is this possible in Struts 1 validator? I know that I can do this in java code, but I'm curious if it can be done in the struts 1 validation.xml file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I added a validate method to my ActionForm with my custom logic based on instructions from [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/951704/1108487).

```
public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
  ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
  if ((phone==null) && (email == null)) 
      errors.add("email", new ActionError("error.phoneOrEmail"));
  return errors;
}
```